# How to get last login date of customer

Tags: magento, magento-1.3

I would like to get the last login date of my customer (on Magento).

I'm doing this way :

```
$customer = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();  
$logCustomer = Mage::getModel('log/customer')->load($customer->getId());  
$lastVisited = $logCustomer->getLastVisitAt();
```

But it doesn't work, the result is NULL

There is a table named "customer_log" in my database, and this table is empty! 
This table has columns : 'customer_id', and 'login_at'.

Do you know if i have to activate an option in the backoffice, to make it works ?

Thanks, and sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 1):

Your table `customer_log` doesn't appear in my Magento 1.3.2 install, however there is a `log_customer` table. It has columns for `log_id, visitor_id, customer_id, login_at, logout_at, and store_id`. The `login_at` column will give you exactly what you want.

```
// $lastVisited = $logCustomer->getLastVisitAt();
// becomes
$lastVisited = $logCustomer->getLoginAt();
```

This will return a MySQL `datetime` (like `2012-06-17 13:45:57`) in UTC, there is also a `getLoginAtTimestamp()` method that you might prefer that returns a Unix timestamp.

Comment: Hi nachito,

Sorry i was talking about 'customer_log', and not 'log_customer'.
However, this table is empty in my database. There are no entries.

Strange, isn't it ?

Comment: @e-niki: Yeah, like I said I don't have that table, it could be from a 3rd-party module. What is your full version of Magento?

Comment: @e-niki: Try enabling the Magento log: System -> Configuration -> Advanced -> Developer -> Log Settings (default is disabled).

Answer (score 1):

For me this is the best way to do it:

```
$customer = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
$logCustomer = Mage::getModel('log/customer')->loadByCustomer($customer);
$lastVisited = $logCustomer->getLoginAtTimestamp();
$lastVisited = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $lastVisited);
```

Comment: For me, `loadByCustomer` works! `load()` passing a customer ID does not. This solution is the one that works!